# Flutter Error: No named parameter with the name 'keyboardType'.keyboardType: TextInputType.text

Tags: flutter

I am new on Flutter and I would like to set up a form. This is my code:

```
const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Nom',
              hintText: 'Entrez votre nom',
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 25,
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              autocorrect: true,
              autofocus: true,
            )),
            const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Prenom',
              hintText: 'Entrez votre Prenom',
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 25,
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            )),
            const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Telephome',
              hintText: 'Entrez votre numero de telephone',
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.phone,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 25,
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            )),
            const TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Mot de passe',
              hintText: 'Entrez votre mot de passe',
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.lock,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 25,
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
              ObscureText: true,
            )),
```

when i run i see this error:

lib/main.dart:48:15: Error: No named parameter with the name 'keyboardType'.
keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart:2522:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const InputDecoration({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:61:15: Error: No named parameter with the name 'keyboardType'.
keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart:2522:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const InputDecoration({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:72:15: Error: No named parameter with the name 'keyboardType'.
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart:2522:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const InputDecoration({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:82:15: Error: No named parameter with the name 'keyboardType'.
keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart:2522:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const InputDecoration({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pull_to_refresh-1.6.3/lib/src/smart_refresher.dart:273:21: Error: The method 'ancestorWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorWidgetOfExactType'.
  return context?.ancestorWidgetOfExactType(SmartRefresher);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pull_to_refresh-1.6.3/lib/src/smart_refresher.dart:277:41: Error: Method not found: 'TypeMatcher'.
  return context?.ancestorStateOfType(TypeMatcher());
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pull_to_refresh-1.6.3/lib/src/smart_refresher.dart:277:21: Error: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorStateOfType'.
  return context?.ancestorStateOfType(TypeMatcher());
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pull_to_refresh-1.6.3/lib/src/smart_refresher.dart:1003:20: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
  return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(RefreshConfiguration);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pull_to_refresh-1.6.3/lib/src/internals/indicator_wrap.dart:631:9: Error: A value of type 'ValueNotifier' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ValueNotifier'.
- 'ValueNotifier' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart').
  ? refresher.controller.headerMode

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code I think your problem has been solved. refer Textfield [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html)

```
 TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          autocorrect: true,
          autofocus: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Nom',
            hintText: 'Entrez votre nom',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 25,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Prenom',
            hintText: 'Entrez votre Prenom',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 25,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Telephome',
            hintText: 'Entrez votre numero de telephone',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.phone,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 25,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Mot de passe',
            hintText: 'Entrez votre mot de passe',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.lock,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 25,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Your result screen like-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          controller: stepcontroller,
                          focusNode: _focusNodes[0],
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Enter Step",
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: _focusNodes[0].hasFocus
                                  ? appcolor
                                  : Colors.grey,
                              // fontSize: 24.0
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                  color: appcolor, width: 2.0),
                              // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            ),
                            // prefixIcon: Icon(
                            //   Icons.person,
                            //   color: _focusNodes[0].hasFocus
                            //       ? Colors.teal
                            //       : Colors.grey,
                            // ),
                          ),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return "   Step  cant be empty";
                            } else if (value.length > contactlist.length) {
                              return "step out of range";
                            }
                          },
                        ),
```

You can try this, it will open numbers keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link to clear understand about `textfiled` properties in Flutter.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html